# Why can't I access my Github repo from CLI

Tags: github, git-bash

I created a repo on Github, and I was able to commit code scripts to the repo from the Git Bash cli. Now, I have entered the `master` of my repo from the cli with `cd reponame`, but I can't commit new files to my Github repo of the same name. I can stage and add, but the command `git commit -m "message"` says my code is committed but when I go and refresh the repo on Github, there is no sign of the file. It didn't behave like this when I first setup the repo. Please, is there something I am not getting right?

Comment: You must also `git push origin master` for code to appear in GitHub

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 1):

after committing use git push so ur changes go to github and can be seen

Comment: this should go in comments, because it's not an answer to the question

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: @Idiaye: Mark this answer as the accepted one, if this was the correct answer to your problem!

Comment: @Luuk: I think it was actually the correct answer to the question.

Comment: I forgot to add git push origin master to push to ur master branch